# How many bytes can be sent in 1 second using Apple Watch Bluetooth (Apple watch 6)?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, watchos, data-transfer, watchconnectivity

I am currently building **watch connectivity between apple watch app and iOS app**. At the start, I want to send over a view model (nested classes) to apple watch, possibly more than 100 objects in total.

One thing I noticed is that my child view model, converted in Json data is measuring up to 400-500 bytes. **Hence, if I want to send a nested view model in Json data, it would amount to 40-50 Kilo bytes, and I am worried that this loading could take pretty long, and problematic if data is too large causing failures during delivery**.

Based on this article (https://www.howtogeek.com/770465/why-apple-watch-updates-and-transfers-are-so-slow/), Apple watch 3 or below uses bluetooth 4.0 that has data transfer rate of 1 Mega byte ps, and **Apple watch 4 or later uses bluetooth 5.0 that has 2 Mbps**.

**Would this mean, transfer 40-50 Kilo bytes of data would be completed within 1 second in reality?**

I am concerned that there are other tasks that Apple watch 6 performs, causing the actual data transfer rates to be lower than the stated bluetooth bandwidth.

Comment: megabits (mbps) are not megabytes per second, 2Mbps roughly equals to 200 kilobytes per second

Comment: Thanks for the correction. At this point, the theoretical speed seem sufficient, but I am worried that the actual bandwidth might be much lower.

Comment: You might find the following article of interest as it talks about calculating an application's data throughput: https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-5-speed-maximum-throughput/

Comment: @ukBaz thanks for sharing the article, it really gives me a better understanding.